# Detect Viewport vs Rendering in Geometry Nodes

Tags: geometry-nodes

I'm trying to scatter some grass on a terrain. With the particle system, you could set different density values for viewport vs rendering. I was wondering if there is a way to do the same in geometry nodes? I looked at the various nodes, and couldn't seem to find one that detects the rendering environment.

This seemed like a pretty essential feature, so I figured there must be a way.

Here are the nodes:

[image]

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

yes you can.

There is now a "is viewport" node.

[image]